# How to use Count(*) with sql joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get row count in SQL Server 2008. I am using join which works perfect, I just want to get the total records because at the moment total records go beyond thousand.

```
select 
    tablet.Approach.ApproachId,StartDateTime,QuestionId 
from 
    Tablet.Approach
join 
    tablet.DataCapture on tablet.Approach.ApproachId = tablet.DataCapture.ApproachId
where 
    QuestionId = 25
```

So that I can see the existing result plus 1 extra field which displays total number of rows

Comment: You question is not clear !! does it matter the total number if it exceed 1000?

Comment: Why don't you do it as 2 separate queries?

Comment: your syntax seems HQL (tablet.Approach.ApproachId is not regular in Sql Server)

Comment: getting this error when i use count (*)

Comment: Column 'Tablet.Approach.ApproachId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: select 
 COUNT(*),MAX(QuestionId) FROM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like  this -

**Solution: 1**

```
SELECT tablet.Approach.ApproachId
    ,StartDateTime
    ,QuestionId
    ,COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalRowCount
FROM Tablet.Approach
JOIN tablet.DataCapture ON tablet.Approach.ApproachId = tablet.DataCapture.ApproachId
WHERE QuestionId = 25
```

**Solution: 2** (Using CTE)

```
;WITH SourceData
as
(
    SELECT tablet.Approach.ApproachId
    ,StartDateTime
    ,QuestionId
    FROM Tablet.Approach
    JOIN tablet.DataCapture ON tablet.Approach.ApproachId = tablet.DataCapture.ApproachId
    WHERE QuestionId = 25

)
,RecordCnt
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(ApproachId) AS TotalRowCount
    FROM SourceData
)
Select * from SourceData Cross join RecordCnt
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select
 count(*),
 tablet.Approach.ApproachId,StartDateTime,QuestionId 
 from Tablet.Approach
 join tablet.DataCapture
 on tablet.Approach.ApproachId = tablet.DataCapture.ApproachId
 where QuestionId = 25
 group by tablet.Approach.ApproachId,StartDateTime,QuestionId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total number of records using window functions, in particular `count()`:

```
select a.ApproachId, StartDateTime, QuestionId,
       count(*) over () as TotalRows
from Tablet.Approach a join
     tablet.DataCapture dc
     on a.ApproachId = dc.ApproachId
where QuestionId = 25;
```

I also added table aliases.  These make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT COUNT(*),tablet.Approach.ApproachId,StartDateTime,QuestionId 
 FROM Tablet.Approach
 JOIN tablet.DataCapture ON tablet.Approach.ApproachId = tablet.DataCapture.ApproachId
 WHERE QuestionId = 25
 GROUP BY tablet.Approach.ApproachId,StartDateTime,QuestionId
```

Comment: Dear, you're missing GROUP BY clause. Not right your answer

Comment: again error with the above answer...not sure why but if i take count(*) off join works perfect, i just need to get the total row count returned by join query